# How can I add elements inside HashMap and save it? [Android]

Tags: android, hashmap, sharedpreferences

I'm new with HashMap, how can I save permanently and add other items when I reopen the application?

For example:

```
 private HashMap<String, Recognition> registered = new HashMap<>();
  public void register(String name, Recognition rec) {
  registered.put(name, rec);
```

}

I can see all items inside registered using:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Recognition> entry : registered.entrySet()) {
    final String name = entry.getKey();
    ... }
```

But when I close and reopen app, I can't see all objects saved inside registered.
I see lot of people using SharedPreferences, but I don't know how to add items inside the pre-saved hashmap.

Comment: a data structure (in this case, the hash map) is simply a way of representing and making use of data in a specific way to achieve something, no data structure has a way of saving the data beyond the lifespan of the application, that's where persistent storage comes in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it indirectly this way:

```
//writing into file
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString( key, hashmap.getValue() );
editor.commit();

//reading from file
SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
for( i = 0;i < size;i++) )
   pref.getString( i , defaultValue );
```